# Integral of $ e^x sinh(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

So far I have

## $\int{e^x\sinh(x)dx}$  =  $\frac{1}{2}\int{e^x(e^x-e^{-x})dx}$

Expanding the brackets I get

## =$\frac{1}{2}\int{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}dx}$

However Wolfram says when I expand the brackets, it becomes

## =$\frac{1}{2}\int({e^{2x}-1)dx}$

Can someone please explain this step to me?

EDIT Sorry just realised $e^x(e^{-x})=e^{x-x}=e^0=1$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions

Answer (score 3):

Simply

$$e^x(e^x-e^{-x})=e^{x}e^{x}-e^{x}e^{-x}=e^{x+x}-e^{x-x}=e^{2x}-e^{0}=e^{2x}-1$$